# Testing a controller that extend Controller class

Tags: php, symfony, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm tries instance a class that extends  `Controller` class

This is my Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class SalaryController extends Controller
{
    public function calculateTotalSalary($id)
    {
        return $this->render('resources/view.html.twig');
    }
}
```

and this is where I want to call the controller

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Tests\Units\Controller\Controller;

use AppBundle\Controller\SalaryController;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\KernelTestCase;

class SalaryControllerTest extends KernelTestCase
{
    public function testExample()
    {
        $controller = new SalaryController;
        $controller->calculateTotalSalary(1);
    }
}
```

When executed the code give me this:

```
Starting test 'AppBundle\Tests\Units\Controller\Controller\SalaryControllerTest::testExample'.
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function get() on null \vendor
symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.php on line 176
```

Line 176 in Controller class:

```
return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($view, $parameters, $response);
```

the $container variable is null, Why ?

Comment: Probably because the kernel is not booted and the DI container is not initialized in the controller. May be this can help you https://php-and-symfony.matthiasnoback.nl/2012/06/symfony2-testing-your-controllers/

Comment: Controllers are not meant to be united tested, you should write functional tests in this case: http://symfony.com/doc/current/testing.html#your-first-functional-test

Comment: As mentioned avoid unit testing a controller.  Move the calculate total salary functionality to it's own SalaryCalculator service and unit test that.

Comment: Oh, yes, it´s logic, At the end, a method inside controller is a URL and it will be a functional test.

Comment: Thanks, from Colombia!